# DRY PHP if block

Tags: php, if-statement, dry

How to write this code more dry? There is something that disturbs me. I am checking if categories and posts are null using an OR condition. However I have to check these two conditions again after login. Yours...

> ```
>         if($app->getCategories()==null || $app->getPosts()==null )
>         {
>             if(isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['password']))
>             {
>                 if($app->login($_POST)!=false)
>                 {
>                     if($app->getCategories()==null)
>                     {
>                         $app->installCategories();
>                     }
>                     if($app->getPosts()==null)
>                     {
>                         $app->installPosts();
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 echo $app->login();
>             }   
>         }
> ```

Comment: I think this is really more of a programmers.stackexchange style question.  Maybe someone could migrate it over?

Comment: Or even code review?

Answer (score 1):

As one way of optimization I would suggest to create logical variables to avoid execution of `getCategories` and `getPosts` methods twice.

As for me it is difficult to suggest other refactorings for your code without knowledge of your app business logic.

```
    $noCategories = $app->getCategories() == null;
    $noPosts      = $app->getPosts() == null;

    if($noCategories || $noPosts) {

        if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

            if($app->login($_POST)!=false) {

                if($noCategories)                    
                    $app->installCategories();

                if($noPosts)                    
                    $app->installPosts();                    
            }
        }
        else {
            echo $app->login();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if($app->login($_POST)) {
        ($app->getCategories() ? '' : $app->installCategories());
        ($app->getPosts() ? '' : $app->installPosts());
    }
} else {
    echo $app->login();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try this : Too many nested ifs are bad for many reasons :(

```
$categories = $app->getCategories(); 
$posts = $app->getPosts();

if($categories == null || $posts == null) {

    if(! isset($_POST['username']) || ! isset($_POST['password'])) {
        echo $app->login();
    }

    if($app->login($_POST) != false && $categories == null) {
        $app->installCategories();
    }

    if($app->login($_POST) != false && $posts == null) {
        $app->installPosts();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$isCategoriesNull = $app->getCategories() == null;
$isPostsNull = $app->getPosts() == null;
$postKeysToCheck = ['username', 'password'];

if ($isCategoriesNull || $isPostsNull) {
    if (!array_diff($postKeysToCheck, array_keys($_POST))) {
        if ($app->login($_POST) != false) {
            if ($isCategoriesNull) $app->installCategories();
            if ($isPostsNull) $app->installPosts();
        }
    } else {
        echo $app->login();
    }
}
```